# Declarative Pipeline jenkins stage build fail early exit job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

How to Declarative Pipeline Jenkins when a stage fails, the subsequent stages do not continue to execute.
I only want use Declarative Pipeline.

This is my sample code.

```
    pipeline{
        agent any

        stages {
           stage('stage 1') {
              steps {
                  echo 'stage 1'
               }
            }
            stage('Stage 2') {
                steps {
                    sh "exit 1"
                    //or do other error thing
                }
            }
            stage('stage 3') {
                steps {
                    echo 'stage 3'
                }
             }
        }
}
```

This is my code run stage view.
[image]
I want to get stage 1 run and stage 2 failed and stage 3 is empty.

My Jenkins version is Jenkins 2.346.1

Example Stage View.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [catchError](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#catcherror-catch-error-and-set-build-result-to-failure) or [warnError](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#warnerror-catch-error-and-set-build-and-stage-result-to-unstable) or a simple `try-catch` to handle your error gracefully and continue the Pipeline. See the example below.

```
pipeline{
    agent any

    stages {
       stage('stage 1') {
          steps {
              echo 'stage 1'
           }
        }
        stage('Stage 2') {
            steps {
                catchError(message: "Something went wrong", buildResult: 'UNSTABLE', stageResult: 'UNSTABLE') {
                    sh "exit 1"
                }
                
                //or do other error thing
            }
        }
        stage('stage 3') {
            steps {
                echo 'stage 3'
                script {
                     try {
                         sh "exit 1"
                    } catch (err) {
                        echo "Failed: ${err}"
                    }                        
                }

            }
        }
        stage('stage 4') {
          steps {
              echo 'stage 4'
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want the pipeline to keep running. 
I just want the pipeline to stop at the failed stage.

like the image I provided.
This picture is from https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-stage-view/ 
So I think the jenkins pipeline can achieve this result.

Comment: @Owen if an error occurs in any stage consecutive stages will not run. That's the default behavior.

Comment: I thought so too at first.
but the result I get after running my simple code is not like this.
I don't know if it has something to do with the Jenkins version